# Match quote delimited string with regex but with exceptions

Tags: regex

Hello I try to check if a quoted string doesn't have `:T` or `:U` at the end.
(I use the .Net Regex Class)

What i have so far is

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1
```

This matches all double and single quoted words, for example `"Test"` and `'Test'`
Where i am stuck is, i don't want the regex to match `"Test":U` or `'Test':U` or `"Test":T` or `'Test':T`

Comment: What is the programming language or regex flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following negative lookahead assertion and anchors:

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1(?!:[TU])
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

See [RegEX Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY7nP3/2)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer but this doesn't semm to work
I have tested it on http://regexr.com and my teststring is "Test":U "Test2":T "Test3" 'Test4' "Test'5" 'Test"6' "Test:U" "Test:T" 'Test:U' 'Test:T'
It should match everything except the first two strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a negative lookahead at the end `(?!:[UT])`. As an aside, you can obtain a more efficient pattern like this:

```
string pattern = @"[""'](?>(?<="")[^""\\]*(?>\\.[^""\\]*)*""|(?<=')[^'\\]*(?>\\.[^'\\]*)*')(?!:[UT])";
```